# Are these yamaha fake?

Tags: guitar

[image]
Here pictures of them , i dont know if they are real or fake ones

Comment: Well, if they’re being advertised as “Yamha” then yeah, they’re fake.

Comment: Can't identify the logo, but if it says 'Yamha' that might well be the marque. But it's not Yamaha...or the logo thereof.

Comment: I can't be sure but that looks like a "Crown" guitar to me. The store that I worked in for a short while sold a lot of them.

Comment: The blue one on the right seems to have a clearly identifiable Yamaha soundhole label inside. The other two seem to have similar labels but it's hard to make out exactly; certainly the logo isn't clearly visible. These labels seems to have different proportions than genuine Yamaha labels, based on a quick Google image search.

Answer (score 3):

Yamaha paper labels inside, C-something (probably Corbin) logo on headstock. Fake.

Yamaha acoustics also tend to have a different headstock shape. Often the shapes of the headstock and body are patented/trade-/service-marked in some way.

The ones in the photo look like a Taylor knockoff headstock.